# extra point at boxplot with with jittered points (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers

I used code below to explore box-plots with `ggplot2`.

```
MyData<-data.frame(CASES=c(rep("Good",10),rep("NotGood",10)), NUMBERS=c(2,3,1,5,6,3,2,6,8,3,1,3,6,8,17,3,2,5,7,20))

library(ggplot2)
MyBoxplot <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=CASES, y=NUMBERS)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
MyBoxplot+ geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.2))
```

**I notice that if my data hasn't any outliers (`Good`), then the box-plot has 10 points, as it should be. But if there are some outliers (`NotGood`), then the outliers get doubled.**

What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: In case of your category "NotGood" geom_boxplot allready plots two outliers. Hence, when adding geom_jitter these two points get doubled.

Comment: @stefan , Ithought that this is the problem, but I couldn't believe it... Can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @stefan said, `geom_boxplot()` automatically will plot the outliers as dots aligned with your x value, so the outlier points are represented twice.  There is no function/argument to "remove" the outlier points from `geom_boxplot()`; however, you can get the same effect by making the outlier points from the boxplot transparent via `outlier.color=`.

As an example, take the following dataset, which has a few outliers.  I've adjusted the shape in `geom_jitter()` to make it easier to see which dots are coming from the outliers (and not the `geom_jitter`).

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(c('A','B'), each=100), y=c(rnorm(100, 10, 20), rnorm(100, 30, 50)))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2), shape=3)
```

[image]

If we set `outlier.color=NA`, that makes those outliers from the boxplot "transparent", so they are no longer observed in the plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color=NA) +
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2), shape=3)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! Finally, I also find some other ways to "remove" outliers, like: `geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)` or `geom_boxplot(outlier.size = -1)`.